# Ignoring popBackStack to destination as it was not found on the current back stack

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem while running my app, but I'm not understanding why.
The problem seems to be when I use popBackStack, however I already use this in other parts of the app and it never happened.
Both of the classes I'm working with are fragments.

**The problem:**

`I/NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination com.example.dissertation:id/explanationFFragment as it was not found on the current back stack`

**explanationFFragment**

```
package com.example.dissertation.ui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.dissertation.R;
import com.example.dissertation.databinding.FragmentExplanationfBinding;

import com.example.dissertation.ui.dashboard.DashboardViewModel;

public class ExplanationFFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentExplanationfBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentExplanationfBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.buttonExf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_nav).navigate(R.id.action_explanationFFragment_to_factsFragment);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**where I'm doing popBackStack**

```
   @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
        for (int i = 0; i < binding.container.getChildCount(); i++) {

            View v = ((LinearLayout) binding.container.getChildAt(i)).getChildAt(0);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (app.rehabActivity.equals("Q")) {
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_nav).popBackStack(R.id.explanationQFragment, false);
                    } else if (app.rehabActivity.equals("F")) {
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_nav).popBackStack(R.id.explanationFFragment, false);
                    } else {
                        Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_nav).popBackStack(R.id.navigation_home, false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Can someone understand whats the problem and help me, please?